# Retriving Facebook posts from Profile via FB api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have registered an app in facebook developers program and I can retrieve posts from facebook page using fb api, but I cannot retrieve posts from facebook profile. Should I use some different access token for both page or profile? Is there a different way for retrieving posts from facebook page and profile? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

Answer (score 0):

You may need the **user_status** permission.

And you call the posts using this graph query **{USER_ID}?fields=statuses**

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:- You need to have valida FB token for all the request:-
I am answering using c# language.
Step 1:- First you need to get the user's FB id using FB token

I am using Facebook SDK 7.0.6 for querying purpose

here's how to initialize the FB service which we will use in our consecutive calls.

```js
FacebookService facebookService = new FacebookService(facebookToken);
var _facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(token);
```

Code snippet

```js
public string GetFacebookID(string facebookToken)
        {
            dynamic result = _facebookClient.Get("me?fields=id");

            if (result.ToString().Contains("id"))
            {
                return result["id"];
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

after that you can execute below method to get user's post using FB ID and token

```js
public List<Post> GetPostsForUser(string facebookID)
        {
            List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();

            dynamic result = _facebookClient.Get(facebookID + "/posts"); //Case Sensitive, Posts doesn´t work

            if (result.ToString().Contains("data") && result.data.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (var item in result.data)
                {
                    posts.Add(new Post
                    {
                        ID = item.id,
                        Story = item.story,
                        Message = item.message,
                        Created_Time = Convert.ToDateTime(item.created_time),
                        Reactions = GetReactions(item.id)
                    });
                }

                result = _facebookClient.Get(GetNextURL(result.ToString()));

            }
            return posts;
        }
```