# How to use Facebook API to get FB user's Like, Post from c#?

Tags: c#, facebook, api

I'm developing a Facebook application using their Graph API..

I've come across a problem in that I can't retrieve the user's Likes, Posts, and User Profile .

How is it possible to retrieve the user's likes, posts using the Graph API?

I know we can use FB's graph api, but how we can execute api using c# for getting User Likes, Posts and User Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below thread to get User's FB post considering yo have FB token already.

[Retriving Facebook posts from Profile via FB api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351988/retriving-facebook-posts-from-profile-via-fb-api/54580053#54580053)

Also to get user's like please follow the below method

```js
   

 public List<Like> GetLikesForUser(string facebookID)
            {
                List<Like> likes = new List<Like>();

                dynamic resultNode = _facebookClient.Get(facebookID + "?fields=likes{ name, created_time, category, category_list}");//likes?fields=likes

                if (resultNode.likes != null)
                {
                    dynamic result = resultNode.likes;

                    if (result.ToString().Contains("data"))
                    {
                        while (result != null)
                        {
                            if (result.ToString().Contains("data"))
                            {
                                foreach (var item in result.data)
                                {
                                    likes.Add(new Like
                                    {
                                        Name = item.name,
                                        ID = item.id,
                                        Category = item.category,
                                        Created_time = Convert.ToDateTime(item.created_time),
                                        Category_List = PopulateCategoryList(item.category_list)

                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            var next = GetNextURL(result.ToString());

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(next))
                            {
                                result = _facebookClient.Get(next);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return likes;
            }

 private List<Category> PopulateCategoryList(dynamic categories)
        {
            List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

            if (categories != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in categories)
                {
                    Category category = new Category { ID = item.id, Name = item.name };

                    categoryList.Add(category);
                }
            }

            return categoryList;
        }
```